# Suppress 0 in the Spotfire visualization

Tags: data-visualization, spotfire, zero, suppress

Is there a way to suppress value 0 in the visualization. My visualization has so much of data and our business team doesn't want to display value 0 in the visualization. is there a way to suppress it. Attaching below the Original output and expected output.
[image]

Thanks
Venkatesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can "hide" the zeros by creating a calculated column with the following expression:

```
If([Fruits] = 0, NULL, [Fruits])
```

but you have to do this for each column you wish to "hide."